# Why is $# always 0 in my function?

Tags: bash, shell, parameter

Bash is driving me nuts. I can't figure out why the following (nor any of the dozens of variations I've literally copied and pasted from examples) fails to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $#

function main {
    if (( $# < 1 )); then
        usage
    fi

    echo "good"
}

function usage {
    echo "Usage: $0 <outputdir>"
    exit 1
}

main
```

For some reason the argument check fails every time, even when I pass an argument and can clearly see `$#` is set as expected.

Comment: See also: [What does ``$#`` mean in shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122343/80216)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're calling the `main` function with no argument. So `$#` in the main function is always 0.

Each function instance has its own arguments. (“Instance” means that if the function is started multiple times (through recursive calls), each call has its own arguments.) The positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc., as well as the associated parameters `$#`, `$*` and `$@` refer to the arguments passed in the function call. For example, if you call `main foo bar` then inside the `main` function the value of `$1` will be `foo`, the value of `$#` will be 2 and so on.

If you want to pass the arguments of the script to a function, use `"$@"`. This construct expands to the list of arguments passed to the script (or to the function, if called inside a function). Note that unlike what normally happens with double quotes, the parameters are passed separately, `"$@"` is a list of strings and not a single string. The double quotes are necessary, otherwise the parameters are not passed as is but treated as a whitespace-separated list of file name patterns.

```
function main {
  if (( $# < 1 )); then
    usage
  fi
  echo "good"
}
main "$@"
```

Comment: As an extra note, the `function foo {` syntax is the `ksh` function definition syntax (as opposed to the Bourne/POSIX `f() {` one) and in `ksh`, with that syntax, `$0` is also overridden inside the function. `$0` is overridden whatever the syntax in `zsh` (unless in `sh` emulation) and is never overridden in other shells like `ash`, `yash` or `bash`.

Comment: this is probably right  answer.

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
NARGS=$#

function main {
    if [ $NARGS -lt 1 ]; then
        usage
    fi

    echo good
}

function usage {
    echo "Usage: $0 <outputdir>"
    exit 1
}

main
```

I left the `set -x` there on purpose. It's useful to debug these errors. If you don't pass any arguments to the `main` function, `$#` becomes 0 inside it (replace `$NARGS` with `$#` in the `if` condition to see this).

Comment: I see! So calling a function clobbers (some of?) the argument variables. Good to know! (Obviously very new to bash, sorry)

Comment: I didn't know either, thus the usefulness of `set -x` :)

Comment: @chaiguy Only `$1`, `$2`, etc get clobbered, as they get re-used for the function arguments. `main $NARGS` is pointless as the argument isn't being used. `$NARGS` becomes `$1` inside the function.

Comment: @DavidBaggerman, Thanks. Edited to correct and avoid confusion.