# What does $# mean in shell?

Tags: shell, shell-script

What does `$#` mean in shell?

I have code such as

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
```

I want to understand what `$#` means, but Google search is very bad for searching these kinds of things.

Comment: For searches with punctuation marks, I like to use symbolhound.com. Usually finds what I need.

Comment: you can  browse the  [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)

Comment: For better referencing and SEO: bang, [number sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign), sharp, U+0023, &#35;, comment sign and dollar!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can always check the man page of your shell. `man bash` says:

```
Special Parameters
   #      Expands to the number of positional parameters in decimal.
```

Therefore a shell script can check how many parameters are given with code like this:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "you did not pass any parameter"
fi
```

Comment: @NoName You can `man` almost anything, including `man` itself. Also try `apropos` some time.

Comment: @NoName you can also, when using an OS with GNU tools (linux, etc) use `info` for either the man page, or additionnal informations (very detailled, and compartmentalized) if the packages has some

Answer (score 15):

Actually,

```
`$` refer to `value of` and
`#` refer to `number of / total number`
```

So together

```
`$#` refer to `The value of the total number of command line arguments passed.`
```

Thus, you can use `$#` to check the number of arguments/parameters passed like you did and handle any unexpected situations.

Similarly, we have

```
`$1` for `value of 1st argument passed`
`$2` for 'value of 2nd argument passed`
```

etc.

Answer (score 9):

That is

1. the number of parameters with which the script has been called
2. the number of parameters which have been set within the script by `set -- foo bar`
3. (when used within a function) the number of parameters with which a function has been called (`set` would work there, too).

This is explained in the bash man page in the block "Special Parameters".